# Android Layout xml file swapping row, and change itself?

Tags: android, eclipse

I have Layout xml file and when i edit it

```
  <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/image1"
        android:text="llllllllllllllllllll"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
```

But it change like,[image]

its happens when i edit xml file.and after closing xml file and i need to `re-open and re-open.`is there any solution ?

i already `restart my eclipse` but can't solve issue.And restart eclipse is not working.is 
there any solution for that ?

Comment: It happens with me also sometimes. But for that i just close the xml and then open it again and then it works fine.

Comment: @Antrromet but it happens more and more with me and headche for me..

Comment: It must be a bug in Eclipse Editor.

Comment: it also happened to me, but updating to the latest SDK made this a lot less common.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=375421

Answer (score 0):

It is a problem with Eclipse editor which I also face often when the change is done by dragging and dropping in Graphical Layout or so. The solution I follow is to close the xml and reopen again.

Comment: @no its not solution it happens many times and i need permanent solution if possible ?

Comment: It is a bug in eclipse. For a permanent solution, we have to wait for Eclipse to update.

Answer (score 0):

It's a **bug** of Eclipse

you can find [here is a bug report](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=375421)

Also facing same problem. Sometimes need to restart eclipse also.

Comment: Wrong issue number. The issue is https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=375421

Comment: @TorNorbye changed link its okey now ?

Answer (score 0):

This problem happens when you edit your relative layout  xml file. To avoid this you can escape this component or close xml file then reopen it.

Comment: i need permanent solution.dont escape from Relativelayout and i already says `reopen and reopen xml file.`